# code only executes with break points

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an asp.net page where I'm trying to upload a document. The cs file of that page has a lot of code. If I insert break points, the below code executes successfully one step at a time, but if I remove the break points, the document doesn't get uploaded. I won't paste the entire code for the page since it is hundreds of lines, but I will paste the code related to document upload.
It starts off by `button_Click()` which calls another function which has the below code.
Notice the code again calls codes `SaveFile` code.

With break points: OK, without break points: not so good.

```
int JobRequestID = JobRequestComponent.CreateNew(description, txtLocation.Text, int.Parse(ddlSiteSelect.SelectedValue), JobSubTypeID, UserID, PriorityID, defectList, JobRequestComponent.EModule.HeadOffice, txtRoomNumber.Text);
int JobID = new SLICDataContext().JobRequests.Where(x => x.JobRequestID == JobRequestID).Select(x => x.JobID.GetValueOrDefault(0)).Single();


if (fu.HasFile && JobID != 0)
{
    int siteID = new SLICDataContext().Jobs.Where(x => x.JobID == JobID).Select(x => x.SiteID).Single();
    int reactiveJobId = new SLICDataContext().Jobs.Where(x => x.JobID == JobID).Select(x => x.ReactiveJobID.GetValueOrDefault(0)).Single();
   // int DocumentID = DocumentsComponent.SaveFileByReactiveJobID(reactiveJobId, GetUserID, fu.FileName,
    //                                                                  fu.FileBytes, txtDescription.Text, 1);

    int DocumentID = SaveFile(siteID, JobID, UserID, fu.FileName, fu.FileBytes, "reactive", null, DocumentBusinessType.General,
                txtDescription.Text, 1);
    SLICToFSGEvents.DocumentUploadedByHeadOfficeUser(DocumentID);
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Is the whole process synchronous?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just as a guess - the JobRequestComponent.CreateNew probably uses a different thread to the UI. Hence when you get to the if statement JobID is still zero (without breakpoints) as the code is running asynchronously. However, when you insert break points you force the code to execute synchronously.

Comment: using .net 3.5 so no threads or tasks if thats what you guys are asking?